# Botão para captura de tela/screenshot no Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile

Estou desenvolvendo um App e necessito que o mesmo faça uma captura de tela, mas não pelo procedimento padrão (botão home + power), e sim por um botão inserido na tela .
O botão já foi criado e está na tela do App, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer com que este botão faça um screenshot?

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  //procedimento        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O procedimento de tirar um print da tela, consiste em desenhar um arquivo de imagem com o conteúdo exibido na tela.

Partindo do principio que você queira também salvar a imagem gerada no cartão SD por exemplo, a solução seria assim:

Adicione no manifest permissão para escrever no cartão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Adicione o código abaixo dentro da função de clique de seu botão:

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
       // String que recebe o endereço da pasta onde será salva o arquivo
       string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path, "PrintDirectory");

       // Busca a view principal de sua aplicação
       View v1 = Window.DecorView.RootView;
        v1.DrawingCacheEnabled=true;

        // Cria uma cache para escrever a imagem do tipo bitmap
        Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CreateBitmap(v1.GetDrawingCache(true));

        // Instancia o arquivo na pasta de destino. Neste caso o nome do arquivo será de acordo com o horário, pois garante que não terá arquivos com nomes iguais
        Java.IO.File imageFile = new Java.IO.File(path, System.Environment.TickCount + ".jpg");

        //  Cria um fluxo de bytes para escrever os bytes capturados da tela         
        System.IO.MemoryStream bytes = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        int quality = 100;


        // Verifica se a pasta destino existe, caso não exista, cria a pasta no cartão SD
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
        if (!dir.Exists)
            dir.CreateSubdirectory(path);


        // Cria um fluxo de escrita para o arquivo destino
        Java.IO.FileOutputStream fo;
        imageFile.CreateNewFile();
        fo = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(imageFile);

        //Converte o bitmap para JPEG
        bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, quality, bytes);

        // Escreve o arquivo com o print na pasta e depois o fecha-o
        fo.Write(bytes.ToArray());
        fo.Close();
}
```

Será gerado um arquivo do tipo .JPEG na pasta escolhida

Comment: a parte que busca a view principal está dando erro 
"Uma refrência de objeto é necessária para o campo,o método ou a propriedade "Window.DecorView.RootView" não estática .

Comment: Você está chamando essa função direto da activity ?
Se sim e o erro persistir, tente trocar o código: `Window.Decor.View`
por:  `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();`

Esse tipo de código pode sofrer alteração dependendo da versão do Android.

Comment: sim, da mesma maneira que foi apresentada na resposta

Comment: vale ressaltar que estou iniciando na programação orientada a objetos/ xamarin

Comment: não estou obtendo sucesso, o problema parece estar no DecorView (especulando)

Comment: Obteve o mesmo erro?
A linha `android.R.id.content`  parte do princípio que este seja o nome padrão da activity, caso não seja, você precisará se adaptar.

Comment: oque você quer dizer com activity? quando mencionou antes, pensei estar falando do button_clicked

Comment: Activity num linguajar menos técnico é cada tela de sua aplicação. Essa propriedade `getRootView` busca o elemento raiz da tela(activity) que você está usando no momento. O evento de clique do botão, tem que estar dentro da activity na qual você deseja tirar o print, por exemplo a MainActivity.
a linha `android.R.id.content` busca o nome padrão mas as vezes pode ter outro nome como por exemplo: `android.R.id.main_layout`. Você pode conferir o nome no arquivo xml de sua activity